# The existence of a countable dense subset of a nonempty compact lattice of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$

Tags: general-topology, proof-explanation, lattice-orders

I'm reading about Tarski's theorem in the lecture note:

> [image]

In the proof of **Lemma 2.13**, the author said that

> Let $D=\left\{d_{1}, \ldots, d_{n}, \ldots\right\}$ be a (finite or) countable dense subset of $A$.

Could you please explain the existence of $D$? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution invokes some basic facts from general topology.

1. $\mathbb R^n$ is *separable* which means that it contains a countable dense subset. "Countable" also includes finite.
2. A metrizable space is separable iff it is *second countable* which means that it has a countable base. In particular $\mathbb R^n$ is second countable (this can also be seen directly).
3. Any subspace of a second countable space is second countable.

Now $A$ is a subset of $\mathbb R^n$, thus $A$ is second countable. Since $A$ is metrizable, we find the desired $D$.